# Hiding/showing layers in legend does not work in QGIS standalone

Tags: pyqgis, layers, legend, standalone, qgsmapcanvas

I'm building a standalone app with PyQGIS. I encountered some difficulties building a canvas that show the result layers after some operations.

The canvas works, but the associated legend does not allow hiding and showing the corresponding layers, despite the use of the appropriated flags.

[image: Displayed canvas, with an unchecked layer still visible]

Here is the code I wrote :

```py
from qgis.core import *
from qgis.gui import *
from qgis.PyQt.QtCore import *
from qgis.PyQt.QtWidgets import *


def combine_extends(layers):
    """Combine extends of all layers"""
    global_extend = layers[0].extent()
    if len(layers) > 1:
        for layer in layers[1:]:
            global_extend.combineExtentWith(layer.extent())
    return global_extend


def set_canvas(window_title, crs_epsg, layers=None):
    """Set a canvas instance with basic configuration
    If layers are provided, render them on canvas"""
    # Basic configuration
    canvas = QgsMapCanvas()
    canvas.setWindowTitle(window_title)
    canvas.setCanvasColor(Qt.white)
    crs = QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem(crs_epsg)
    canvas.setDestinationCrs(crs)
    # Optionnal layers rendering
    if layers:
        render_layers(canvas, layers)

    canvas

    return canvas


def render_layers(canvas, layers):
    """Render layers on canvas and refresh it"""
    # Set layers to render, and define an adapted zoom level
    try:
        canvas.setExtent(combine_extends(layers))
        canvas.setLayers(layers)
        canvas.zoomToFullExtent()

    except:
        raise Exception("Error while rendering layers")


def add_legends(project, canvas, layers):
    # Some more tests

    layer_tree_root = project.layerTreeRoot()
    bridge = QgsLayerTreeMapCanvasBridge(layer_tree_root, canvas)

    # Cleanup persisting former layers_group in RAM
    if layer_tree_root.findGroup("Layers"):
        layer_tree_root.clear()

    layers_group = layer_tree_root.addGroup("Layers")
    for layer in layers:
        layers_group.addLayer(layer)

    model = QgsLayerTreeModel(layer_tree_root, layer_tree_root.findGroup("Layers"))
    model.setFlag(QgsLayerTreeModel.AllowNodeReorder)
    model.setFlag(QgsLayerTreeModel.AllowNodeRename)
    model.setFlag(QgsLayerTreeModel.AllowNodeChangeVisibility)
    model.setFlag(QgsLayerTreeModel.ShowLegend)

    tree_view = QTreeView(canvas)
    tree_view.setHeaderHidden(True)
    tree_view.setModel(model)

    bridge.setCanvasLayers()
    print(str(canvas))


def render(project, canvas, layers):
    render_layers(canvas, layers)
    add_legends(project, canvas, layers)

    # handle canvas refresh
    canvas.show()
    canvas.refresh()
    canvas.repaint()
```

I call `render` once all processings are done.

QGIS version: 3.22.4,
Environment: Ubuntu WSL

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`QgsLayerTreeMapCanvasBridge` must be in global scope. But you define `bridge` in `add_legend` method's scope. Therefore, variable `bridge` is gone after `add_legend` finished.

One of the solutions:

- Add `bridge = None` above the line where you call the `render` method

  ```
  ...
  ...

  bridge = None

  render(project, canvas, layers)
  ```
- Then add `global bridge` to top of the `add_legend` method:

  ```
  def add_legends(project, canvas, layers):
      global bridge

      # other lines
  ```

[image]

Comment: Thank you !

I took the liberty to lightly adapt your suggestion, essencially creating the bridge then passing it as arg to my render method. :

```python
## Creating the bridge between canvas and project to syncronize the UI
layer_tree_root = project.layerTreeRoot()
bridge = QgsLayerTreeMapCanvasBridge(layer_tree_root, canvas)

# Processing

# Rendering final layers
print("Rendering maps...")
render(canvas, bridge, layer_tree_root, reprojected_trimmed_layers)
```